# Adding views to RecyclerView dynamically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 2 viewTypes in my RecyclerView - A and B

A gets it's data from adapter. B is a custom view with totally different layout and makes it's own web-service call for data.

So I have 2 ViewHolders in total (one for A, one for B). My requirement is to show B only if it has successfully fetched all data from server. So, initially I am making the visibility of B view to GONE, and resetting to VISIBLE when it has data to show.

The problem with this approach is that dividers (set using ItemDecoration) for B views are showing even while content is GONE. This is causing big gaps in the RecyclerView while B views are loading. If they fail to load, I remove B views, so that part is not a problem.

Looking at the ItemDecoration API I don't think there is a way to conditionally show dividers.

So I am looking for a way to create the B views outside of RecyclerView and then add the view itself to RecyclerView. Is it possible ? Or is there a better solution to my problem ?

One possible workaround is to drop ItemDecoration and instead add margins to views A and B, and reset the margin of B to from 0 to higher value when data is received. I haven't tested this approach, but I would like to avoid it, because I have too many viewTypes (A and B being just two of them) and most of them are custom views whose layout I will have to change.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you a common list from where you'll populate your `RecyclerView`. So when the B items are finished with their service calls they will be inserted in that common list accordingly and the changes in the list can easily take effect by calling `notifyDatasetChanged` on the adapter.

So here's a common class I would like to propose.

```
public class CommonClass {
    public ClassA;
    public ClassB;
    public ClassC;

    // .... You can put other classes here as you need to populate all the items in a single list

    // You can set this tag like "A" to specify this object is a A type object. 
    // This is necessary when you'll populate the items in your list. 
    // You'll check the tag first in your `getView` method and will take actions accordingly after checking the tag. 
    public String tag;
}
```

Now take a list of `CommonClass` and then populate the items. When the web service calls are finished you may repopulate the data in that list and then call `notifyDatasetChanged` in your `Adapter`.